# Regex for comparison expression

Tags: c#, regex, match

I need to match strings like the following:

```
( anything >= anything )
```

and there can by only these comparison operators: >= <= == != < > And they can be there only once.
What I have is:

```
^\(.+(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=).+\)$
```

But it matches stuff like >=!= and so forth.
I did look through the stackoverflow questions and googled but couldn't find the right solution.

Clould you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex like `^\(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-\/* ]+\s*(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-\/* ]+\s*\)$` should do the trick, right?

[A Regex101 with it in action can be found here.](https://regex101.com/r/zQ3pQ7/1)

Comment: I'm afraid, no... By "anything" I meant that it could also be like the following: ( a + b >= a - g[i, j+d] )

Comment: This is a really fast regex, however, it can only match arithmetic comparisons. Also, it is a bit misleading: `[A-z]` captures also "[ \ ] ^ _ and \` (remove `_` in your regex, and you'll still capture this symbol), and `+-\/` creates a range that also captures `,`, `-`, and `.`. The symbol `/` does not need escaping in C# regex flavor. And finally, regex101.com is not the right service to test .NET regular expressions since it does not support them (although PCRE engine is really similar to the greater extent).

Comment: This is all true; I'm really not used to C#'s regex flavor, especially since JavaScript's version doesn't have nearly as many features. I've tried to change the regex to be more accurate - thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

If you are also planning to also capture strings like `(myName == "Денис")`, you need to use the following regex:

```
^\((?>(?![<>=]=|!=|[<>]).)*?(?:[<>=]=|!=|[<>])(?>(?![<>=]=|!=|[<>]).)*?\)$
```

See [demo on Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C((%3F%3E(%3F!%5B%3C%3E%3D%5D%3D%7C!%3D%7C%5B%3C%3E%5D).)*%3F(%3F%3A%5B%3C%3E%3D%5D%3D%7C!%3D%7C%5B%3C%3E%5D)(%3F%3E(%3F!%5B%3C%3E%3D%5D%3D%7C!%3D%7C%5B%3C%3E%5D).)*%3F%5C)%5Cr%3F%24&i=(%20anything%20%3E%3D%20anything%20)%0D%0A(%20anything%20%3C%3D%20anything)%0D%0A(%20anything%20%3D%3D%20anything)%0D%0A(%20anything%20!%3D%20anything)%0D%0A(%20anything%20%3C%20anything)%0D%0A(%20anything%20%3E%20anything)%0D%0A(%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3E%3D%20a%20-%20(%20c%20-%20g%5Bi%2C%20j%2Bd%5D)%20)%0D%0A(%20%3E%3D!%3D%20)&o=m) (supporting .NET regex flavor, unlike regex101.com)

It is much faster than Karthik Manchala's suggestion as per testing results at http://regexhero.net, due to the use of [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (`(?> ... )`), [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[<>=]`), and  and lazy matching (`*?`). Also, in case a space is missing before or after `==` operator, my regex will still capture the expression.

With `(?m)^\((?>(?![<>=]=|!=|[<>]).)*?(?:[<>=]=|!=|[<>])(?>(?![<>=]=|!=|[<>]).)*?\)$` my regex yields 15,783 iterations per second, and Karthik's
`(?m)^\(((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+\s+(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)\s+((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+\)$` yields 9,204 iterations per second speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
^\(((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+\s+(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)\s+((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+\)$
```

Explanation:

- `((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+` any character other than `(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)`
- `\s+(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)\s+` one of the operators followed by
- `((?!(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)).)+` any character other than `(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)`